# How do I load a single query in PowerQuery to multiple sheets within a workbook?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have one query which I then reference four more times in order to load the exact same table 5 times within a workbook. Is there a way of just loading the one query to 5 different locations within the workbook without having to create 4 more queries which just reference the initial query? Currently this is slowing the performance as each 'Refresh All' results in the 5 queries being all refreshed

Comment: Load the Powerquery data into the excel workbook as a Pivot Table report. Then copy the pivot to as many places as you want in the workbook, even changing the format and fields, and they will all refresh from the same source.  If necessary, you can mimic a plain data table this way as well

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in Power Query to have the one query then you can reference or duplicate it.

Duplicate is a copy of the data with all the same steps. Reference will only have the one step, which is get data from the referenced data set. In this case you will need to [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries) it.

Right click on the dataset and select the reference option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jon interpretation of "reference" is wrong. Using "reference" will still re-run the referenced query. "reference" only makes the overall code more succinct and dynamically pegged to the referenced query (in case if you edit the referenced query). It does not reduce the querying steps, and hence will never achieve your desirable performance.